# ipad:How to open keynote file on uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadDocument:@"mykeynote.key.zip" inView:webView];
}
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView1
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView1 loadRequest:request];
}
```

I received a error message after run this code "Sorry, this document can't be viewed."I am currently working keynote 09.How do i open the keynote file in uiwebview? Help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some information about it here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

Specifically what you're looking for is this:

> iWork '09 documents do not use a package format and must not be ZIP compressed.

So you shouldn't be compressing your keynote file. This was only required for '08 and earlier.

Since older iWork documents are packages, they are directories. You can use `NSFileManager`'s `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` function along with the key `NSFileType` to see if it's a directory (value should be `NSFileTypeDirectory`).

If the file is a directory you can use a library like [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) to compress it.